# Recover a Windows XP administrator password

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

I've got a computer that's stuck on the main screen asking me for the administrator password.

I think that there is software that can help you recover or change passwords on an XP machine.

Does anyone know or can recommend one?

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). You can burn it to a CD, boot from it, and change the password from there.

Comment: This seems to work well enough.  It's been a long time since I've done anything like this, so I downloaded the ISO image and ran it against a VM of XPsp3.  I first tried resetting the Administrator password to something new, but that failed to work for some reason.  However, for my second attempt, I chose the "clear password" option and that worked like a charm.  Nice utility.

Answer (score 1):

our partner HTG has a relevant article:

Reset Your Forgotten Password the Easy Way Using the Ultimate Boot CD for Windows
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/reset-your-forgotten-password-the-easy-way-using-the-ultimate-boot-cd-for-windows/

Same basic approach, burn a bootable CD that allows resetting the admin password.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [OphCrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Which uses rainbow tables (as I remember.. whatever those are) to try to guess the password.