# Windows 7 I need to know how to reset the password!

Tags: windows-7, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 administrator Password lost! How can I login windows 7 without password?](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password)

I do not have any disks for windows 7 and can not access anything from my computer. Is there anyway I can reset the password? Is there a master password or something I can do? Oh and I only have one account on the computer.

Comment: @Josh K: please don't manually add the "Possible Duplicate" link section -- those are automatically added by the system when the question is closed.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password

Answer (score 2):

You can [boot from a Linux CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/) to reset the Windows password.

Of course, that assumes the Windows partition is not encrypted (in that case, you've lost).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've handled this in the past was to use (or build if you don't have one) a BartPE ([BartPE website](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BartPE)) and use Sala Password Renew ([sala source](http://www.kood.org/windows-password-renew/)).

Boot from the BartPE, either build the PE with sala password renew, or put it on a USB drive and run it once the PE has loaded. Sala password renew allows you to set/reset the password for any Windows accounts on the computer.

**UPDATE:** see another thread related to yours: [Lost my Windows 7 admin password, need to change or reset it](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password)