# Data recovery for OS X

Tags: macos, data-recovery, livecd

I've got a Mac that won't boot and I'd like to recover whatever data I can before wiping the hard drive and reinstalling.  I'm looking for something similar to [TRK](http://trinityhome.org) (which is Windows-centric) — boot from CD, mount the hard drive, and copy to a network share.

I just noticed TRK does appear to support HFS+; has anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately did use TRK, which *does* support HFS+.  I had to do a fair amount of Googling to get mounting to work, but I ended up with this:

```
# mount -r -t hfsplus /dev/sda2 /sda2
```

`-r` mounts the drive read-only (to avoid any further damage to data) and `-t hfsplus` tells it you're mounting a HFS+ partition.  (`hfsplus` didn't show up in the man page or with `man -?` – I spent at least half an hour figuring that one out.)

I then mounted a shared drive on a Windows server.

```
# mount -t cifs -o username=**** //server-ip/share /mnt0
```

It will ask for your password and mount the share.

Since my Windows server runs Windows Server 2008, I had to allow unsigned SMB connections.  (I was getting the error `smb signing is mandatory and we have disabled it`.)  Fire up regedit and navigate to

```
 HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

and change `requiresecuritysignature` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), which is free, open source, and has some similar capabilities.  It's on the [Knoppix Live](http://www.knoppix.net/) CD along with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: does this work also with APFS?

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Alex - agreed you should get an external harddrive to perform the deposit point next time. I think your just adding extra complications to the recovery actions that you probably dont need.

Taking the drive out of the laptop, using a 2.5 ata connector, bought from any computer parts store and placing it in a desktop pc or an external harddrive case, then run your recovery software of choice. Ask a friend for loan of pc or laptop if you dont have a spare computer to work with.

I personally use 2 types.  "R-Studio" which recovers any type of file system, runs on windows, or BackTrack bootable linux cd. Have tried many many others, but these 2 will always stay in my kit.

Comment: External drives cost money; using software to copy to my existing file server is free.  Also, taking the hard drive out of a MacBook Pro [voids the warranty](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/apple-notebooks/102307-hard-disk-upgrade-path-unsupported-apple.html), which means that is not an option.