# How can I login to my dads PC without knowing his password?

Tags: windows-vista, login, passwords

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)
>   [Windows 7 administrator Password lost! How can I login windows 7 without password?](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password)

My dad passed away 2 weeks and I cant find his password anywhere. The password hint is "car reg" but I have tried all the cars that he has had.

I dont want wipe the PC but he is the admin user and I wont be able to install anything for my mum.

Any ideas? Its Windows Vista!

Answer (score 5):

I used [offline NT edit](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/) for the job. Its a single utility but it works like a charm to clear out passwords, add/remove users and so on. With this I was able to get my Win7 back. Also fully compatible with XP and Vista of course.

Comment: This will reset the password. Any encrypted files will no longer be readable. First try Ophcrack just in case.

Comment: Hmm you got a point there. Didn't think about encryption but sure thats better in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) - It can look up the password for most windows systems and tell you what the old password was instead of changing it.

Did you try the car registration number or license plate #, both with caps and with lower case?

Answer (score 1):

real simple... u just need KON-BOOT disk
you can get cd-image from http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/

it's a few KB download, burn it over any CD... then boot from CD as Primary Device
a Kon-Boot screen will come; press enter and it will move onto starting Windows Vista...

when the normal log-in screen comes, just enter any fake password and it will accept...

this way you don't need to change/wipe original password and trick Vista to allow you log-in

Answer (score -1):

Download a copy of the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ubcd4win.com/index.htm) and burn to a blank CD from another PC - then boot from this CD and there are a number of tools on it to crack Windows passwords.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: -1: It would be helpful if you pointed what those tools were.