# Windows 7 password

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 administrator password lost! How can I log into Windows 7 without a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-log-into-windows-7-without-a-pas)

I reset my password (windows 7) a week ago and now have totally forgotten the password. How do i reset the password?

Comment: A duplicate of a duplicate? What...?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have whole-hard drive encryption (such as BitLocker), you can use Petter Nordahl-Hagen's Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/7 [offline password editor](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/).

- This is a utility to (re)set the password of any user that has a valid (local) account on your Windows NT/2000/XP/2003/Vista system, by modifying the encrypted password in the registry's SAM file.
- You do not need to know the old password to set a new one.
- It works offline, that is, you have to shutdown your computer and boot off a floppy disk or CD. The boot-disk includes stuff to access NTFS partitions and scripts to glue the whole thing together.
- Works with syskey (no need to turn it off, but you can if you have lost the key)
- Will detect and offer to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts!

Answer (score 2):

If it's an simple password (such as a word you'd find in a dictionary), the [Ophcrack live cd](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) can break it in a matter of seconds.

Get the Vista edition, as Windows 7 uses the same login system as Vista.

Answer (score 1):

[Kon-Boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/)

Kon-Boot live cd in its current compilation state it allows to log into a linux system as 'root' user without typing the correct password or to elevate privileges from current user to root. For Windows  systems it allows to enter any password protected profile without any knowledge of the password.