# Windows 7 Administrators password

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I forgot my Windows 7 password. What now?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/i-forgot-my-windows-7-password-what-now)

Is there an easy way of resetting my administrators password other than buying an expensive tool? Thank you

Comment: And [Windows 7 administrator password lost! How can I log into Windows 7 without a password?](http://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-log-into-windows-7-without-a-pas)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite Windows password reset tool, easiest one to use.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcloginnow/

.