# How to regain control of a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 administrator password lost! How can I log into Windows 7 without a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-log-into-windows-7-without-a-pas)

My employee left the company and its Windows is locked by a password. There is no other account to choose. I don't want to ask him the password nor format the machine. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I would download ntpassword, found [this](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html) web page. All you need to do is just boot to the disc and it will step you through a command line interface that will allow you to clear the password of the operating system. Most answers to the command line can be answered correctly with the default answer (by pressing Enter) If you need any help, please comment.

-Good Luck

Comment: Why a down vote? At least leave a reason.

Comment: I didn't down vote.

Comment: you may have missed it, but somebody downvoted YOUR answer.  Xavierjazz was just asking why.  I'm kinda wondering about that too... for obvious reason.

Comment: The posted is no longer valid - 404 error.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, thanks for letting me know. I just went to the site and found the link that shows all of the images and updated the link.

Answer (score -1):

Just boot virtually any Linux CD live version and copy off the work related files you need from the employee's hard drive.  I prefer Ubuntu but lots of live versions are out there the would work just as well.  At that point you have the option of reformatting and reinstalling Windows - or not.  If you choose not to reformat then you can use one of several tools that are available (under Linux again) to clear the password and set your own password.

You could also take him to court to get him to reveal the password.  Personally I'd ask first and then if he proves reluctant to give you the password you have the other two (or three) alternatives.