# Offline Password & Registry Editor for Windows

Tags: windows, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lost my Windows 7 admin password, need to change or reset it](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/lost-my-windows-7-admin-password-need-to-change-or-reset-it)

Dear community!
I need to Backup, Restore, Modify the Local users passwords under NT/2k/XP/Vista/Win7.

Is there any tool that can do it [only bootable livecds?]?

Can someone please post a howto regarding it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will get you where you need to go.

[Lost my Windows 7 admin password, need to change or reset it](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/lost-my-windows-7-admin-password-need-to-change-or-reset-it/95805#95805)

The backup and restore part could easily be done with a flash drive.

Answer (score -2):

[Ehow](http://www.ehow.com/how_7191657_reset-password-linux-boot-cd.html) has a short howto.

In fact, [techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-linux-rescue-tools-for-recovering-linux-windows-or-mac-machines/1458) has a great article on all sorts of rescue tools.

Comment: Why on earth is a link to a step by step article talking about how to do exactly what he's asking, (he even asks for a link to a howto in the question) worthy of a downvote?