# How can I access the Windows Administrator account after forgetting the password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, password-recovery

I am using HP Mini running Windows 7

I have forgotten admin account password and I am  not able access it but I have access to standard account

Using account that I am not able to install any software.

How can I access the Administrator account?

Comment: Reinstall windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost my Windows 7 admin password, need to change or reset it](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/lost-my-windows-7-admin-password-need-to-change-or-reset-it)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options. The easiest I've found is to make a bootable USB or burn a disk with [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

You can boot to the drive/disk and load the registry and erase the password.

1. Boot to CD.
2. Let it try the automatic drivers.
3. Select the Drive/Partition your Windows is installed.

   #### Generally the largest but that's not always the case
4. Select the path to your Registry.

   #### It will default you to the normal: `Windows\system32\Config path`.
5. Choose Option 1 for Password reset
6. Choose Option 1 for Edit Users
7. Enter the ID for the User you want to reset the password for.
8. Option 1 to erase the password.
9. Use 'q' to back out twice.
10. When it asks you if you want to save your changes use 'y'

You can then reboot and you should be able to get into the account without issue.

There are a handful of useful YouTube videos that walk you through the whole process.

[Here's one YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3sn-PjamLw)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and burn (passcape iso) and boot it from the dos. It has lots of options on how to access & decrypt the file where the passwords are store. Otherwise you can change the password.