# I cannot remember my windows 7 password. How do I bypass it or recover it?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I forgot my Windows 7 password. What now?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/i-forgot-my-windows-7-password-what-now)

I cannot remember my windows 7 password. How do I bypass it or recover it? This is a brand new computer that came with windows 7 already installed on it.

Comment: duplicate of [I forgot my Windows 7 password. What now?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/i-forgot-my-windows-7-password-what-now)

Answer (score 1):

[Offline NT Password and Registry Editor.](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)

Quote from their site:

- This is a utility to reset the password of any user that has a valid (local) account on your Windows NT/2k/XP/Vista/Win7 etc system.
- You do not need to know the old password to set a new one.
- It works offline, that is, you have to shutdown your computer and boot off a floppydisk or CD or another system.
- Will detect and offer to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts!
  There is also a registry editor and other registry utilities that works under linux/unix, and can be used for other things than password editing.

Comment: Used it myself on Vista and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do in the case where the password was added recently, **without using third party software**, is to boot to the Windows CD (if you have one! but I think any Windows 7 disk should work) and [do a manual System Restore to before you set the password](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/forgot-lost-administrator-password-windows-7/) (you can't do this in Windows itself without the admin password, obviously!)

If you haven't put much on the machine yet that you care about losing, you might just do a complete factory recovery - I'd need to know details of the machine to advise how you'd go about this but pretty much all major OEMs ship some method of doing it these days.

I highly also recommend you make a password reset disk so this doesn't happen - this option is on the sidebar in the User Accounts settings (where you'd actually go to make or change your password) and I believe it may give you a link when you actually set a password as well.