# Change password of windows vista with "net user" command, Vista not accepting password

Tags: windows-vista, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I forgot my Windows 7 password. What now?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/i-forgot-my-windows-7-password-what-now)

I changed the password using "net user aditya aditya^Aaditya". But the problem is now Vista is not accepting this password. When I type '^', nothing appears, but when I enter it twice, then 2 characters appear, I erase one of them and then type the rest of the password. But it is not accpeting this password. I dont have password reset disk also. Please help me. I have a very critical data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I forgot my Windows 7 password. What now?](http://superuser.com/q/72244/4377)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the net user command interpreted ^A as ctl-A and it borked.  You may need to reset the password and try escaping/single-quoting if you want to use carat in a password

Comment: How do I reset password?

Comment: search this site...that has been answered many times

Comment: `net user` doesn't do such an interpretation. (No Windows program does that I know of.) However, the command shell `cmd.exe` treats `^` as an escape character, similar to how Unix `bash` uses a backslash.