# Removing ThinkPoint malware from a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, malware

I have a Windows 7 box infected with the fake Thinkpoint anti-malware program. I do not have  of the admin password on this computer. I did find what appears to be some [good instructions at BleepingComputer.com](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-thinkpoint) to remove this, but am unsure on how to proceed.

1. Has anyone successfully removed this malware ( if so, can you recommend steps )
2. If I need to get into an admin account on Win 7, what is the best way? I have used Ultimate Boot CD in the past on XP boxes, but have not done so on 7 yet.

Comment: 1. I'd start with http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware 2. http://superuser.com/questions/72244/i-forgot-my-windows-7-password-what-now/72270#72270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is to get into safe mode.  To do this, while the PC is booting up, press F8.  A list of startup options should be listed.  CHoose Safe Mode.

**How to remove ThinkPoint manually:**

Manual removal of ThinkPoint is a feasible objective if you have sufficient expertise in dealing with program files, processes, .dll files and registry entries.

The files to be deleted are listed below:

```
* %UserProfile%\Application Data\hotfix.exe
* %UserProfile%\Application Data\thinkpoint.exe
```

The registry entries that need to be removed are as follows:

```
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\PAV
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run “thinkpoint”
* HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon “Shell” = “%Documents and Settings%\[UserName]\Application Data\hotfix.exe”
```

(taken from: http://remove-malware.net/how-to-remove-thinkpoint-rogue-anti-spyware/)