# Retrieve admin password

Tags: password-recovery

How do I retrieve the admin password if I have forgotten?
I have changed the default password to something else. Now I can not login since I do not remember the new password.

Comment: What OS? Do you have any other accounts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html) bootdisk can reset passwords.  It's free and I've had good results with it in the past.

> More or less tested from NT3.5 up to Windows 7, including the server
>   versions like 2003 and 2008. Also 64 bit windows supported.