# Forgot Windows 7 Password, How to Get in Your Password Protected PC?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

I forgot amin Password of my login account, i'm using Win7, can here anyone help me to get it back?

Comment: I hope you made a [password reset disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-password-reset-disk).

Comment: Have you tried the "Administrator" account in failsafe mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the admin password with the [windows offline password changer disk](http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) - there's instructions on the site on how to do so- its pretty much creating a live cd or usb, booting into it and following the instructions. There's dodgier ways - actually recovering the old password with brute force methods for example, but most take longer, or are... dodgy.