# Lost access to only account in Win7, how to recover password?

Tags: windows-7, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

I have a friend who bought a new Win7 computer, and he set it up with a new (admin) account and password, and now when he tries to log in with the password he set he gets "The password you have typed is incorrect, check spelling/caps etc..."

Since it seems to have set a different password on that account, and that is the only account on the machine, there is no way to log in, so standard password-recovery tools like Cain&Abel or Ophcrack won't work.

Are there any ways to reset a password without being logged in?

**EDIT:** Duplicate realized, see @Paul 's comment. Voting to close.

**EDIT #2:** It was a misspelled password; he was able to recreate the misspelling and log in to change the password back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your installation doesn't have drive encryption enabled, you can use this tool to "clear" the passwd for the account, it can be downloaded as a LiveCD

Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor, Bootdisk / CD
http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html