# Crack a password and username on windows vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

The adminstrator account was disabled and all that is left is the "other user" (as it calls it).

How can I gain access to the computer?

Comment: Can you boot from a CD?

Comment: i tried ophcrack and some other that i cant even remember

Comment: [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/72270#72270)

Comment: Cracking a password is more difficult. But using tools like Og Cuck, Hirens boot CD you can "disable" any password. Basically it clears the password from the password database file. No encrypted password = no password. This takes less than 3 minutes from boot to restart into desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) for this. Burn it to a CD, boot off it, and you can reset the administrator password.

Comment: even if the adminstrator account was disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I have no reason to believe Gooler's suggestion won't work but the one on Hiren's 10.4 will do that and will activate the account if desired even if it is deactivated.

Comment: Yea Hirens boot CD can "clear" the password, disable and enable other accounts. Hirens also has cracking tools but it will take years on a standard computer to crack or brute a Windows password.