# Locked out on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Have a notebook with Windows 7 Pro.

Standart installation, added 2 accounts; admin & "a power user". I'm locked out due to the power-user locking each account.

How can I gain access again ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, booting in Safe Mode will always enable the built-in "`Administrator`" account and bypass its restrictions. Need to test, though.

Comment: Try the advice grawity gave, if you can't access that account you may be able to retrieve the passwords using something like `OPHCrack` or reset them with the `Offline NT Password Editor` tool.

Answer (score 0):

use Hiren's Boot C, it has got a plenty of pwd recover/reset tools.
http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd