# Reset disk does not work for different model of computer

Tags: windows-7

I've created a reset USB disk on my HP computer, with Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit, and it works fine.

However, it does not work for Acer computers (notebooks too), so what is the problem here? I've have created it for the same user named `user`, and the password is exactly the same as well.

Is it possible to show the language bar with a keyboard shortcut at the logon screen in Windows 7? I know I can do it through Control Panel, but I can't log into the system. When I click *Reset Passwword*, it shows me my USB flash drive and says that the password hint is on this USB drive.

Then I click *Next* and type the new passwword, then confirm this new password, but an error dialog is shown. It says that an error occured when trying to change the password for this user-

Answer (score 1):

User accounts created on different machines are different accounts, even if they have the same name.

A [password reset disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows-vista/Create-a-password-reset-disk) is only usable for one account.

If this were not so, I could reset your password on your machine by creating an account of the same name on my machine and creating a password reset disk on my machine. This would be a security problem.

Comment: so what i could do?

Comment: @dato: You could create a separate password reset disk for every account on every computer. You could set up a Windows domain instead (if you have a suitable Windows server)

Comment: i can't it  ,model is acer  computer and even i can't reinstall system

Comment: @dato: See http://superuser.com/q/72244/52492