# no password to unlock admin acct. Not even with the disc. EVERYthing needs admin password

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords

I have a computer that is completely controlled by the administrator password.  I cannot reboot with the disc w/o the password.  User account is controlled with a main password.  i cannot upload any files with out a password.   How do I disable the admin account and add a new one without the password.

Comment: You can't boot to disc?

Comment: Who put the password(s) on the machine?

Comment: Just the password to the account or change the permissions on the user account

Comment: THis site is not about hacking.

Answer (score 2):

**In order to disable an administrator account (or change it's password), you would have to speak to the administrator.**

---

**BIOS Passwords:**

If what you are asking about is a BIOS Password, you can [reset this by finding the CMOS reset jumper](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdp_L5IxaNI) on the motherboard. It typically involves removing the jumper, moving it to the reset position, then moving it back. On many motherboards, unplugging from a power source and removing the BIOS battery for a few minutes should reset it as well. I would not recommend doing this to someone with limited IT experience, as if there are any important settings in your BIOS that are reset, you may put your PC in an unbootable state.

**Windows Passwords:**

If you **are** the administrator (ie. you **own** this computer and it's in **your** home or **your** business), and you forgot the password you set, then you must format the hard drive and reinstall Windows. In the future, you can [create a password reset disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-password-reset-disk) to recover forgotten passwords.

There are ways to remove administrative passwords using boot disc tools, but that kind of information could be considered "black hat" technique and might be best researched elsewhere, if you are the administrator of the machine.

There is a similar question about this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password).

---

**Note about "Hacking" methods:**

If this community were to provide information or resources for someone to gain access to another password-protected account (even if it helped someone of good intentions), it could be used by another person reading to do something malicious. This is why we won't (or *shouldn't*) provide explicit instruction on how to remove a Windows administrative password.