# Locked out of windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

Suspecting a virus I set windows 8.1 to boot to safe mode and then restarted the pc. I am now asked for my admin account password but cannot recall it. What can I do to access windows 8.1  Prior to this I was accessing my machine using a pin which I can recall, but now that option does not seem available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows 7 password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-7-password)

Comment: Can't you just reboot back to normal windows, enter your pin, then set an admin account password and boot back into safemode?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest solution is to boot a copy of NTOFFLINE or something similar but if you suspect a virus a refresh or reset is probably a better choice. If you hold down shift when you reset the computer you will boot into the advanced boot options menu and from there you can choose to refresh (Backup data..wipe...restore data) or reset (wipe everything)

Comment: I have tried the boot options, but whenever I choose an option I am asked for the admin password. Is there a way I can force it to ask for the admin pin cos I can remember that.

Comment: There should be a "Sign in options" button at the login screen that you can look for which allows you to submit the pin rather than the password. If that method doesn't work you will have to reset the admin pass  with a bootable disk like ntoffline or a Hirens boot cd

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you have a spare CD/USB and PC to download [Hiren's Boot Disk](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd). Burn it onto a CD/DVD/USB and then boot up onto it.

There are a number of password removal tools, try them one by one until one unlocks it. I suggest you try [WindowsGate](http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=21204) first, which is on Hiren's disk.