# Logging into a windows 7 system which is under domain when IP block change

Tags: networking, login, dhcp, domain, windows-domain

I'm having a very interesting trouble. I've a PC under a domain. But I can't login even though I know **current credentials** the account.

The PC was **manually** set to an **IP** and our SA **changed** our **IP blocks** now. DHCP users easily switched involved new IP block but owing to my PC IP's being manually set I can't login with current credentials.

Is there any way of switching IP to automatic DHCP without login ?

Is it possible to change interface settings over disk by replacing disk to another PC?

Or is there any other possible workaround ?

*it's a windows 7*

Comment: Log in as the local admin and set it to DHCP. Done.

Comment: Our SA set it. He does not remember local account details.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I know my current credentials , I just let windows to use DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Log in with an administrator account that's local to the machine (as it won't require a domain controller to authenticate), and use that account to configure the networking to use DHCP.

If you (and/or the admin of the computer) can't remember the local Administrator account password, then please take a look at this SU question for some solutions for resetting that password:

[What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-7-password)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems it won't be easy for me. Because I do not know local account.

Comment: Use the [SetHC.exe hack](http://superuser.com/a/247953/23133) provided in one of the answers on the suggested question, create a new user, add it to the local admin group, login as that user, done. ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you can't get your login parameters validated on the domain host, because your IP is blocked in requesting login validation there. Here are some different things to try:

1. Boot up in safe mode (F8 at bootup time) and switch settings to DHCP.
2. Or, with existing login situation, click the "switch user" button, and when specifying the
   user, prefix it with your pc name (ex:  "mywin7pc\\d.Gurbuz"  )
   [double backslash separator]
3. Or, Ask your SA to temporarily unblock your IP.