# Reset windows 8.1 administrator password

Tags: windows-8.1

I own a machine that is running Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. It has an user account with limited rights - where I can login and the Administrator account for which i forgot the password. Both accounts are local and the computer doesn't belong to a domain.

Is there any possible way of resetting or removing the Administrator password?

Comment: This question shouldn't be marked as duplicate as it has a different accepted answer (which is also more relevant to newer Windows versions) to the original linked question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Option 1

There is, but you need to have the Windows (7|8|8.1) install media available.

1. Start your PC off the (Disk|USB|HDD) that contains the install media
2. Once loaded, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. This will open a command prompt
3. Run the following commands in order:

   ```
   diskpart
   list vol
   ```
4. Once you find the right volume (your `C:` drive (it may have a different drive letter)), run `exit`
5. Now, run `D:` where `D` is your drive letter.
6. Run `cd \Windows\System32`
7. Run `ren Utilman.exe Utilman_old.exe`
8. Run `copy cmd.exe Utilman.exe`
9. Reboot

Once you get to the logon screen, click the `Accessibility Options` icon. Once the Command Prompt opens, run these commands, replacing `user_to_change` with the user you want to reset the password of:

```
net user user_to_change *
```

Enter a new password, enter it again (you won't see it) and log in. You can now go back to `C:\Windows\System32` and delete the `Utilman.exe` that we made, and rename `Utilman_old.exe` to `Utilman.exe`

---

### Option 2

Boot your PC off [Kon-Boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) and it will allow you to log in without any password, and change your password (just don't do it through `Security Options` (the Ctrl+Alt+Delete menu)

---

### Option 3

> You can reset your password using another tool called Hiren's BootCD.
>
> Download Hiren's Boot from http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/,
>   unzip it and use BurnCDCC.exe to burn the ISO to a DVD.
>
> Boot using Hiren's Boot on your locked PC and in the menu shown select
>   Offline NT/2000/XP/Vista/7 Password Changer and click Enter twice (for
>   confirmation and to continue for the list of Linux Kernel Boot).
>
> In the following prompt select the correct drive where the Windows is
>   installed. Press Enter to confirm that your registry directory is
>   Windows/system32/config.
>
> On the chntpw Main Interactive Menu select [1](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) for Edit user data and
>   passwords
>
> Select the user you want to reset the password by typing the username
>   and hitting Enter
>
> There you have a list of options for this user. [1](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) should be for
>   Clear the password. After successfully resetting your forgotten
>   Windows password, type “!” to close the User Editor Tool.
>
> Now type “q” and hit Enter to close the Offline Password Editor and
>   Registry tool.
>
> Now type “y” and hit Enter to confirm the password change.
>
> Now it will ask you whether you want to use it again or not. Just type
>   “n” and hit Enter.
>
> Remove your CD and restart the PC and your user shouldn't have a
>   password anymore.
>   [Source](https://superuser.com/a/838101/418553)

---

### Option 4

Download and boot [Offline NT Password Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) and follow the instructions to wipe out the password.

---

You can use any one of these methods, they all work the same, and you'll end up with access to the Administrator account again.

Comment: Thanks for all your options. I found option 1 most comfortable for me and it worked great.

Comment: Option 5: Boot the computer of your favorite Linux distribution, get 'chntpw' and 'ntfsprogs' if not yet available. Mount the filesystem of your Win 8.1 and run 'chntpw' on your /Windows/System32/Config/SAM file and follow instructions to wipe the Administrator password.

Comment: Can't you use the Windows7 way on Windows8.1? On Windows7, if you forgot a password, you could replace a specific file with a copy of `cmd.exe` to run the command line. From there, you could disable the password and have full access.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'll refer you to `Option 1`

Comment: @TD.512 Sorry, my fault. Here, have my +10. That is the easiest way

Comment: Option #1 worked great but if you need to activate an existing or create a new administrative local user account then you'll need to reboot for them to appear on the login screen.

Comment: wow option 1 was so easy! my computer is dual boot, I just rebooted on linux, renamed the .exe's and went from there. I was not anticipating such a simple process! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Boot up any other system which gives you access to your files. now rename the file on `c:\system32\Utilman.exe` to eg Utilman.exe.bak and then copy `c:\system32\cmd.exe` to Utilman.exe

now boot up the windows system and before you log in, hit win+u (should be) and you have got a cmd with root access. now you can reset the password with

```
net user
```

Comment: no, I wrote at the same time, but you provided a better and faster solution....

Comment: It did work really well on Windows 8.1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Commander ERD64 Disc can reset the admin password...boot with the disc and access locksmith option.