# Run arbitrary program from lock screen or login screen

Tags: windows-10

I'd like to run an arbitrary program from the lock screen or login screen of windows 10. That is without having to enter the password you can run this program. The program I want to run is not one of the apps that you can select for the lock screen and that just display information. 
Is this possible?

Comment: This info might help: http://superuser.com/questions/952206/reset-windows-8-1-administrator-password

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the tool utilman.exe which is meant to be a help for disabled users and allows you to open the on-screen-keyboard, magnifier and other things. Try to replace the file utilman.exe in \windows\system32\ with any other executable and restart your computer. On the Login screen click on Help and see what happens.

Comment: I can't replace utilman.exe. I get the message that I need permission from TrustedInstaller to make changes to this file.

Comment: If you open the WIndows Explorer and navigate to C:\WIndows\System32\ and look for utilman.exe, rename it to utilman.exebak and then copy your executable into the same folder and rename it to utilman.exe. If you get message from TrustedInstaller then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to use the Admin account for that. Not a standard account with admin privileges, but the actual builtin Admin account. Use `net user Admin /active:yes` in an elevated command prompt to see on the login screen, and `net user Admin /active:no` to hied it again.

Comment: @Steven that's what I did, from the windows explorer try to rename utilman.exe and first it asked to provide administrator permission and then permission from TrustedInstaller, what can be wrong in this operation?

Comment: @NathanShiraini I run the net user command in a admin cmd, the command completed successfully but when I tried to rename utilman.exe it said "Access is denied"

Comment: @martinako did you try to rename utilman.exe from your own account or from the Admin account? The only effect of this command is to activate the builtin Admin account so you can see it on the logon screen, it does not change anything for your own account.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, the ultimate solution is to use a Linux live CD/DVD/USB key to access the file and rename it. I've already done that several times, it always worked. However, you may have to tweak BIOS/UEFI settings first if you want to use that solution.

Comment: I added the admin account and from it I tried to rename utilman.exe and again I got the pop up saying I need permission from TrustedInstaller. I'll have to try from a linux live USB key.