# Is there a way to make my Windows account password unresettable using non-official Windows methods?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I found this thread that discusses different ways of resetting the admin password without actually knowing the password [Reset windows 8.1 administrator password](https://superuser.com/questions/952206/reset-windows-8-1-administrator-password). I tried it myself and after no less than 5 mins, I was able to reset my password using method 1. Is there a way to make these methods not work on my device? My account is only local by the way. If I connect a Microsoft account, will that make those methods unusable?

Comment: encrypt your c: drive with bitlocker.

Comment: Enabling BitLocker and Secure Boot would indeed prevent anyone from accessing the WinRE.  Any configuration changes would require the BitLocker recovery key.  “ If I connect a Microsoft account, will that make those methods unusable?” - You cannot reset a local account password using that method but the local Administrator account would be enabled so it wouldn’t be necessary