# Windows 10 locked account

Tags: passwords, windows-10

I upgraded to win 10 2 days ago, and now my laptop cant log in. When I enter my CORRECT password, it says "Your password is wrong", and say that I can change my password. Even when I changed my password in a different computer, it's not working in the win 10 laptop.
Any help, Please. I'm stuck without laptop now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: Assuming you have the correct account maybe the updated password is not available on the laptop yet because it does not have an internet connection.  Try using a wired connection.

Comment: @Jonathan is this resolveddd....?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running the [sticky keys hack](http://lifehacker.com/5612487/hack-the-sticky-keys-feature-to-reset-a-forgotten-windows-password) assuming your hard drive is unencrypted. You'd need a live CD of some sort, whether that's of the linux variety or Windows recovery.