# User Account Control Bypass without login administrator

Tags: windows-8, administrator, uac

Is another way to bypass this if you encounter this window with administrator user?

The user and password of all PC is unknown, I don't want to reformat the whole PC just remove all administrator rights or bypass the account.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score 0):

you have only way to crack the windows password. For this there is many tools but one i've found which definately works in every windows im sharing the complete guide and downloading link for removing windows password

http://goo.gl/lgYEmP