# Reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: windows

I am the only user of my Toshiba laptop, but I don't have administrator priveleges anymore and the admin password that I created does not work. I try anything and I am blocked by group policy. How can I reinstall Windows 7?

Comment: If you are "blocked by group policy" does this mean you are joined to a domain? If so you probaby should not just reinstall Windows... You should talk with your IT department. If it is a mistake that you are not admin they should be able to fix it, if not then you should not try to circumvent the rules your IT admins set.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinstall your computer! You can boot into safe mode and then reset your password with the command prompt.

Net Users (Username) *

Is the command. 
Just replace (username) with the admin username.

Answer (score 0):

You should have bootable USB or cd for you to format your laptop it is better because you have all the privileges and as good as new you will set your own settings whatever you want.

Answer (score -2):

The question seems to be how to reinstall Windows; search for "Digital River media Windows 7" or use an/the install disc for Windows 7 for your laptop.

However, if you'd like to keep data intact, enable the **Admin** Account, then change the password for the user in question.

Comment: Can the administrator account be enabled without admin rights in the first place?

Comment: @bertieb Yes, see this answer [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/a/333063)