# Windows 10 Administrator account has been disabled. Please see your system administrator

Tags: windows-10, administrator, user-profiles

I recently had a problem after installing Windows 10 which required me to start in Safe Mode to rectify it. Since this I can no longer "restart" and the only screen that comes up is:

> Administrator
>
> Your account has been disabled. Please see your system administrator.
>
> OK

When I click "**OK**", nothing happens, I can't get into another screen, I can not log in as administrator nor as myself as it just doesn't have any other screen options to select.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You may have to reinstall W10 if there is no active admin account to log into to fix this problem, which appears to be your issue.

Answer (score 10):

> I can not log in as administrator nor as myself as it just doesn't go
>   into another screen.
>
> Is there anything I can do?

One way to do this is the reset the local administrator password assuming the hard drive is not encrypted with whole disk encryption, and do this by following the below instructions.

---

### **Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor, Bootdisk / CD**

**(Change Windows User Account Passwords Offline)**

*Use if you, forgot your local Windows OS account password, you need to change the local administrator account password, or perhaps need to enable a local user account that's disabled.*

---

***Use this bootdisk to boot PCs with Windows OSes to blank out the `LOCAL` user account passwords, `ENABLE` or `DISABLE` LOCAL user accounts, etc.***

*You can use this if you've forgotten your `LOCAL` Windows user account password, you've done a factory reimage/reset on your Windows OS and the account has a password you don't know what it is, and things of this sort of nature so you can log into Windows as some account WITHOUT a password just to get in, and then set the password from the Windows Control Panel, etc. to something you do know afterwards.*

---

***THE STEPS IN BRIEF***

**1.** Download the bootdisk image file

**2.** Burn bootdisk image file onto media (e.g. `USB` or `CD`) to boot PC from it rather than the hard drive or Windows.

**3.** Put the newly burned bootdisk media into the PC, and then instruct the PC to boot from it rather than the internal hard drive with Windows installed.

**4.** Follow the instruction from the below section labeled `INSTRUCTIONS ONCE BOOTED TO` for what options to pick, etc. to enable existing local Windows accounts and/or blank out the password of the accounts and so on.

---

### **General Information**

***Resource:*** http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html

> **Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor, Bootdisk / CD**
>
> I've put together a CD or USB Drive image which contains things needed
>   to reset the passwords on most systems.
>
> The bootdisk should support most of the more usual disk controllers,
>   and it should auto-load most of them. Both PS/2 and USB keyboard
>   supported.
>
> More or less tested from NT3.5 up to Windows 8.1, including the server
>   versions like 2003, 2008 and 2012. Also 64 bit windows supported.
>
> **DANGER WILL ROBINSON!**
>
> **If password is reset on users that have EFS encrypted files, and the system is XP or newer, all encrypted files for that user will be
>   UNREADABLE! and cannot be recovered unless you remember the old
>   password again** If you don't know if you have encrypted files or not,
>   you most likely don't have them. (except maybe on corporate systems)
>
> Please see the [Frequently Asked
>   Questions](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/faq.html) and the
>   version history below before emailing questions to me. Thanks!

---

### Download Bootdisk

***Resource:*** http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html

> **Download**
>
> Note: Some links may be offsite.
>
> CD release, see below on how to use
>
> - [cd140201.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/cd140201.zip) (~18MB) - Bootable CD image.
> - [usb140201.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/usb140201.zip) (~18MB) - Files for USB install
>
> Previous release:
>
> - [cd110511.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/cd110511.zip) (~4MB) - Bootable CD image.
> - [usb110511.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/usb110511.zip) (~4MB) - Files for USB install
>
> The files inside the USB zip are exactly the same as on the CD. See
>   below for instructions on how to make USB disk bootable.
>
> Floppy release (not updated anymore), see below on how to use them
>
> - [bd080526.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bd080526.zip) (~1.4M) - Bootdisk image
> - [drivers1-080526.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/drivers1-080526.zip)
>     (~310K) - Disk drivers (mostly PATA/SATA)
> - [drivers2-080526.zip](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/drivers2-080526.zip)
>     (~1.2M) - Disk drivers (mostly SCSI)
>
> Previous versions may sometimes be found here (also my site)
>
> **NOTE: Versions before 0704xx will corrupt the disk on VISTA/win7/8!**
>
> **NOTE THAT THE BOOTDISK CONTAINS CRYPTHOGRAPHIC CODE, and that it may be ILLEGAL to RE-EXPORT it from your country.**

---

### HOW TO USE

***Resource:*** http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html

> ### How to use?
>
> <sub>Please read the walthrough (now a bit outdated, sorry) and the
>   FAQ before mailing me questions</sub>
>
> If you have the CD or USB, all drivers are included.
>
> **Overview**
>
> 1. Get the machine to boot from the CD or USB drive.
> 2. Load drivers (usually automatic, but possible to run manual select)
> 3. Disk select, tell which disk contains the Windows system. Optionally
>      you will have to load drivers.
> 4. PATH select, where on the disk is the system? (now usually
>      automatic)
> 5. File select, which parts of registry to load, based on what you want
>      to do.
> 6. Password reset or other registry edit.
> 7. Write back to disk (you will be asked)
>
> **DON'T PANIC!! - Most questions can usually be answered with the default answer which is given in [brackets]. Just press enter/return
>   to accept the default answer.**
>
> [The walkthrough and instructions is now on its own page! but is quite old.. hope to make a new one..](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/walkthrough.html)
>
> ### What can go wrong?
>
> Well. Lots of things, actually. But most of the problems is of the
>   type "cannot find" something. And then nothing happens.
>
> Also, see the [FAQ](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/faq.html) for
>   help with common problems.

---

### **INSTRUCTIONS ONCE BOOTED TO**

*It may be best to print these instruction and then follow from that printed copy—and print from the version on the web site resource URL perhaps too in case they update something with it since after my post here.*

*This is the detail that explains what options to pick once the bootdisk starts booting to find and point to the internal hard drive and pick the current Windows OS objects to blank out the LOCAL user accounts on that Windows OS on the hard drive.*

*This part may seem complex or involved at first, but just let the bootdisk boot up and go through the screen until it prompts or waits for you to tell it what to do. Look over these instructions and just pick the appropriate options as instructed—it should make sense so just read it over until you get it.*

---

***Typically though you'll. . .***

a. pick the Windows disk partition on the hard drive the bootdisk
   inspects

b. from the list of usernames it finds, type the name of the account
   you'll change (e.g. administrator, jsmith, etc.)

c. from the next list, it'll tell you if the account is disabled, expired, etc. so you know what you'll need change to reset it for specifically to ensure you can sign on with it afterwards when booted back to Windows

d. on the next screen you'll want to unlock the account, blank the password on the account or set account as local administrator (option 1, 3, and 4).

- i. you may need to do step "d." one time per action and then pick the username of the account again for the next action if it needs
  more than one action completed (e.g. blank password, unlock account,
  etc.)
- ii. I'd just steer clear of setting passwords here and just do that through Windows Control Panel once you get signed onto Windows with a blank password as administrator, etc.

e. be sure you select "Y" to save your changes to and then when the PC reboots, let it reboot to Windows and then sign on with the blank password to the account you changed with the bootdisk.

---

*If it doesn't work, boot to the bootdisk and do it again, maybe you didn't pick some option so it didn't do what you expected it to. Since you're factory wiping this hard drive anyway, there should not be much danger in loosing anything or corrupting anything as then you'd just reimage/factory reset it again.*

***Resource:*** http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/walkthrough.html

```
Offline NT Password & Registry Editor, Walkthrough

2014, NOTE: This is now a bit old, some are the same, some look a bit different..

The following is a walkthrough of using the CD to reset one user (admin) on a test Vista computer.

Insert the CD and convince your BIOS that it should boot from it. How to boot from a CD varies from computer make to computer make, so I cannot help you much. Some BIOS shows a boot device select menu if you press ESC, F8, F11 or F12 or something like that during the self test. (some even tell you on the screen what to press)

If it boots, you should see this:

  ISOLINUX 3.51 2007-06-10  Copyright (C) 1994-2007 H. Peter Anvin



***************************************************************************   *                                                                         *   *  Windows NT/2k/XP/Vista Change Password / Registry Editor / Boot CD     *   *                                                          
*   *  (c) 1998-2007 Petter Nordahl-Hagen. Distributed under GNU GPL v2       *   *                                                        
*   * DISCLAIMER: THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTIES!          *   *             THE AUTHOR CAN NOT BE HELD RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE       *   *             CAUSED BY THE (MIS)USE OF THIS SOFTWARE
*   *                                                                         *   * More info at: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/                       *   * Email       : pnh@pogostick.net                                         *   *                                                                         *   * CD build date: Sun Sep 23 14:15:35 CEST 2007                            *   ***************************************************************************

  Press enter to boot, or give linux kernel boot options first if needed.   Some that I have to use once in a while:   boot nousb       
- to turn off USB if not used and it causes problems   boot irqpoll        - if some drivers hang with irq problem messages   boot nodrivers      - skip automatic disk driver loading

  boot: Usually just press enter here. If you have linux knowledge, you can tweak kernel options if you need/like.

Then it boots and outputs a lot of kernel messages about your hardware and such.. most if not all are nothing to worry about.


  Loading vmlinuz..................   Loading scsi.cgz.........................

  Loading initrd.cgz..........   Ready.   Linux version 2.6.22.6 (root@athene) (gcc version 4.1.1 20060724 (prerelease) (4.1.1-3mdk))
#2 Sun Sep 9 16:59:48 CEST 2007   BIOS-provided physical RAM map:    BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009f800 (usable)    BIOS-e820: 000000000009f800 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)    BIOS-e820: 00000000000ca000 - 00000000000cc000 (reserved)    BIOS-e820: 00000000000dc000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)    BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000316f0000 (usable)    BIOS-e820: 00000000316f0000 - 00000000316ff000 (ACPI data)    BIOS-e820: 00000000316ff000 - 0000000031700000 (ACPI NVS)    BIOS-e820: 0000000031700000 - 0000000031800000 (usable)    BIOS-e820: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec10000 (reserved)    BIOS-e820: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000 (reserved)    BIOS-e820: 00000000fffe0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)   792MB LOWMEM available.   Zone PFN ranges:
    DMA             0 ->     4096
    Normal       4096 ->   202752   early_node_map[1] active PFN ranges

 ...

  Serial: 8250/16550 driver $Revision: 1.90 $ 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled   serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A   Floppy drive(s): fd0 is 1.44M   FDC 0 is a post-1991 82077   RAMDISK driver initialized: 16 RAM disks of 32000K size 1024 blocksize   USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver v3.0   Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...   usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage   USB Mass Storage support registered.   serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1   serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12   usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid   drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-core.c: v2.6:USB HID core driver   Using IPI Shortcut mode   BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found   Freeing unused kernel memory: 144k freed   Booting ntpasswd   Mounting: proc sys   Ramdisk setup complete, stage separation..   In stage 2   Spawning shells on console 2 - 6   Initialization complete!

  ** Preparing driver modules to dir /lib/modules/2.6.22.6   input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /class/input/input0

Most of the generic linux boot now done, and we try to load the disk drivers. If you use the floppy version you will be asked to swap floppies at this point. Drivers are then tried based on PCI hardware indentification.

  ** Will now try to auto-load relevant drivers based on PCI information

  ---- AUTO DISK DRIVER select ----   --- PROBE FOUND THE FOLLOWING DRIVERS:   ata_piix   ata_generic   mptspi   --- TRYING TO LOAD THE DRIVERS   ### Loading ata_piix   scsi0 : ata_piix   scsi1 : ata_piix   ata1: PATA max UDMA/33 cmd 0x000101f0 ctl 0x000103f6 bmdma 0x00011050 irq 14   ata2: PATA max UDMA/33 cmd 0x00010170 ctl 0x00010376 bmdma 0x00011058 irq 15   ata2.00: ATAPI: VMware Virtual IDE CDROM Drive, 00000001, max UDMA/33   ata2.00: configured for UDMA/33   scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5   sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 1x/1x xa/form2 cdda tray   Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20

  ### Loading ata_generic

  ### Loading mptspi   Fusion MPT base driver 3.04.04   Copyright (c) 1999-2007 LSI Logic Corporation   Fusion MPT SPI Host driver 3.04.04   PCI: Found IRQ 9 for device 0000:00:10.0   mptbase: Initiating ioc0 bringup   ioc0: 53C1030: Capabilities={Initiator}   scsi2 : ioc0: LSI53C1030, FwRev=01032920h, Ports=1, MaxQ=128, IRQ=9   scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     VMware,  VMware Virtual S 1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2    target2:0:0: Beginning Domain Validation    target2:0:0: Domain Validation skipping write tests    target2:0:0: Ending Domain Validation    target2:0:0: FAST-40 WIDE SCSI 80.0 MB/s ST (25 ns, offset 127)   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 83886080 512-byte hardware sectors (42950 MB)   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 83886080 512-byte hardware sectors (42950 MB)   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through    sda: sda1   sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk

Most of these messages are from the drivers themselves. Some talk a lot, some doesn't. But all give info on the brand and model and size of the disks found, if any.


  -------------------------------------------------------------   Driver load done, if none loaded, you may try manual instead.  
-------------------------------------------------------------


  ** If no disk show up, you may have to try again (d option) or manual (m).

You can later load more drivers..



*************************************************************************   * Windows Registry Edit Utility Floppy / chntpw                         *   * (c) 1997 - 2007 Petter N Hagen - pnh@pogostick.net                    *   * GNU GPL v2 license, see files on CD                                   *   *                                                                       *   * This utility will enable you to change or blank the password of       *   * any user (incl. administrator) on an Windows NT/2k/XP/Vista           *   * WITHOUT knowing the old password.                                     *   * Unlocking locked/disabled accounts also supported.                    *   *                                                                       *   * It also has a registry editor, and there is now support for           *   * adding and deleting keys and values.                                  *   *                                                                       *   * Tested on: NT3.51 & NT4: Workstation, Server, PDC.                    *   *            Win2k Prof & Server to SP4. Cannot change AD.              *   *            XP Home & Prof: up to SP2                                  *   *            Win 2003 Server (cannot change AD passwords)               *   *            Vista 32 and 64 bit                                        *   *                                                                       *   * HINT: If things scroll by too fast, press SHIFT-PGUP/PGDOWN ...       *   *************************************************************************

  =========================================================   There are several steps to go through:
  - Disk select with optional loading of disk drivers
  - PATH select, where are the Windows systems files stored
  - File-select, what parts of registry we need
  - Then finally the password change or registry edit itself
  - If changes were made, write them back to disk

  DON'T PANIC! Usually the defaults are OK, just press enter
               all the way through the questions

  =========================================================   ¤ Step ONE: Select disk where the Windows installation is  
=========================================================

  Disks:   Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes

  Candidate Windows partitions found:    1 :        /dev/sda1   40958MB BOOT

Here it has found one disk with one partition

  Please select partition by number or    q = quit    d = automatically start disk drivers    m = manually select disk drivers to load    f = fetch additional drivers from floppy / usb    a = show all partitions found    l = show propbable Windows (NTFS) partitions only   Select: [1]

Here you select one of the partitions listed above (in this case there is only one) or one of the letters from the menu.

Floppy users may need to do 'f' to load in more drivers from another floppy.

The 'd' option will re-run the PCI scan and start relevant drivers (they must already be loaded from floppy with 'f' option)

The 'm' for manual load will present a list of all the drivers with short description if available, and allow you to specify which to load. (Dependecies are handled automatically)

Here we only have one partition, so we just press enter to select it.


  Selected 1

  Mounting from /dev/sda1, with filesystem type NTFS

  NTFS volume version 3.1.

It was an NTFS filesystem, and it mounted successfully.


  =========================================================   ¤ Step TWO: Select PATH and registry files  
=========================================================   What is the path to the registry directory? (relative to windows disk)   [WINDOWS/system32/config] :

The registry is usually system32/config under WINDOWS or WINNT directory, depending on the windows version (and it may be changed during installation). If the correct partition has been selected, the default prompt will be adjusted to match if it can find one of the usual variants.

We accept the defaults.. and get a (bit filtered) directory listing showing most of the interesting registry files


  -rw-------    2 0        0          262144 Feb 28  2007 BCD-Template
-rw-------    2 0        0         6815744 Sep 23 12:33 COMPONENTS   -rw-------    1 0        0          262144 Sep 23 12:33 DEFAULT   drwx------    1 0        0               0 Nov  2  2006 Journal   drwx------    1 0        0            8192 Sep 23 12:33 RegBack  
-rw-------    1 0        0          524288 Sep 23 12:33 SAM   -rw-------    1 0        0          262144 Sep 23 12:33 SECURITY   -rw-------    1 0        0        15728640 Sep 23 12:33 SOFTWARE   -rw-------    1 0        0         9175040 Sep 23 12:33 SYSTEM   drwx------    1 0        0            4096 Nov  2  2006 TxR   drwx------    1 0        0            4096 Feb 27  2007 systemprofile

  Select which part of registry to load, use predefined choices   or list the files with space as delimiter   1 - Password reset [sam system security]   2 - RecoveryConsole parameters [software]   q - quit - return to previous   [1] :

Choice 1 is for password edit, most used. But if you wish, you can load any of the files (just enter it's name) and do manual registry edit on them.

But here, we select 1 for password edit, some files are copied around into memory and the edit application is invoked.


  Selected files: sam system security   Copying sam system security to /tmp

  =========================================================   ¤ Step THREE: Password or registry edit  
=========================================================   chntpw version 0.99.5 070923 (decade), (c) Petter N Hagen   Hive  name (from header): <\SystemRoot\System32\Config\SAM>   ROOT KEY at offset: 0x001020 * Subkey indexing type is: 666c <lf>   Page at 0x44000 is not 'hbin', assuming file contains garbage at end   File size 524288 [80000] bytes, containing 11 pages (+ 1 headerpage)   Used for data: 288/250904 blocks/bytes, unused: 15/23176 blocks/bytes.

  Hive  name (from header): <SYSTEM>   ROOT KEY at offset: 0x001020 * Subkey indexing type is: 686c <lh>   Page at 0x8b4000 is not 'hbin', assuming file contains garbage at end   File size 9175040 [8c0000] bytes, containing 2117 pages (+ 1 headerpage)   Used for data: 96982/6224016 blocks/bytes, unused: 4381/2830032 blocks/bytes.

  Hive  name (from header): <emRoot\System32\Config\SECURITY>   ROOT KEY at offset: 0x001020 * Subkey indexing type is: 666c <lf>   Page at 0x6000 is not 'hbin', assuming file contains garbage at end   File size 262144 [40000] bytes, containing 5 pages (+ 1 headerpage)   Used for data: 334/17312 blocks/bytes, unused: 7/3008 blocks/bytes.


  * SAM policy limits:   Failed logins before lockout is: 0   Minimum password length        : 0   Password history count         : 0


  ======== chntpw Main Interactive Menu ========

  Loaded hives:   

    1 - Edit user data and passwords
    2 - Syskey status & change
    3 - RecoveryConsole settings
        - - -
    9 - Registry editor, now with full write support!
    q - Quit (you will be asked if there is something to save)


  What to do? [1] ->

This demo shows selection 1 for password edit, but you can also do other things. Note that 2, Syskey may be dangerous! AND NOT NEEDED TO RESET PASSWORDS! and does not work at all on Vista, but you get some info before you do any changes.

Selection 3, RecoveryConsole is only relevant for Win2k, XP and 2003 and you must have selected to load the SOFTWARE part of the registry (selection 2) earlier.

The manual registry editor is always available, it is not the most user-friendly thing, but anyway..

We continue our quest to change our "admin" users password..


  ===== chntpw Edit User Info & Passwords ====

  | RID -|---------- Username ------------| Admin? |- Lock? --|   | 03e8 | admin                          | ADMIN  |          |   | 01f4 | Administrator                  | ADMIN  | dis/lock |   | 03ec | grumf1 |        |          |   | 03ed | grumf2                         |      |          |   | 03ee | grumf3                         |        |      |   | 01f5 | Guest                          |        | dis/lock |   | 03ea | jalla1                         | ADMIN  | *BLANK*  |   | 03eb | jalla2                         |        | *BLANK*  |   | 03e9 | petro  | ADMIN  | *BLANK*  |

This is a list of all local users on the machine. You may see more users here than in the overly user-friendly control panel, for example XP has some help and support built in users. The users marked "ADMIN" are members of the administrators group, which means they have admin rights, if you can login to one of them you can get control of the machine.

The buildt in (at install time in all windows versions) administrator is always RID 01f4. This example is from Vista, and Vista by default has this locked down (the installer instead asks and makes another user the regular use administrator, in this case RID 03e8)

The "lock?" collumn show if the user account is disabled or locked out (due to many logon attempts for example) or BLANK if the password seems to be blank.

We select to edit the "admin" user (this was the user made administrator by the Vista installer)


  Select: ! - quit, . - list users, 0x - User with RID (hex)   or simply enter the username to change: [Administrator] admin

  RID     : 1000 [03e8]   Username: admin   fullname:   comment :   homedir :

  User is member of 1 groups:   00000220 = Administrators (which has 4 members)

Group 220 is THE BOSS GROUP! :)

  Account bits: 0x0214 =   [ ] Disabled        | [ ] Homedir req.    | [X] Passwd not req. |   [ ] Temp. duplicate | [X] Normal account  | [ ] NMS account     |   [ ] Domain trust ac | [ ] Wks trust act.  | [ ] Srv trust act   |   [X] Pwd don't expir | [ ] Auto lockout    | [ ] (unknown 0x08)  |   [ ] (unknown 0x10)  | [ ] (unknown 0x20)  | [ ] (unknown 0x40)  |

  Failed login count: 0, while max tries is: 0   Total  login count: 3

Some status info, user is locked out if "Disabled" is set or "Failed login count" is larger than "max tries" policy setting. This user is not locked in any way. The lockout can be reset with option 4 below.

  - - - - User Edit Menu:    1 - Clear (blank) user password    2 - Edit (set new) user password (careful with this on XP or Vista)    3 - Promote user (make user an administrator)   (4 - Unlock and enable user account) [seems unlocked already]    q - Quit editing user, back to user select   Select: [q] > 1   Password cleared!

Here we just reset/clear/blank the password. But you can also try to set a new password with option 2, but it will only work if the password is not blank already. Also, it often fails to work on XP and newer systems.

Number 3 is to put a non-admin user into the administrators (220) group, thus making the user an administrator. IT IS STILL EXPERIMENTAL AND IT MAY sometimes RESULT IN STRANGE ERRORS WHEN LATER EDITING THE GROUP FROM WINDOWS! Also, usually pointless in promoting the Guest user, as it is most likely forbidden to log in by the security policy settings.


  Select: ! - quit, . - list users, 0x - User with RID (hex)   or simply enter the username to change: [Administrator] !

Exclamation point ! quits out (it's SHIFT 1 on the US keyboard layout used on the boot CD) Then we get back to the main menu, and select to quit..


  ======== chntpw Main Interactive Menu ========

  Loaded hives: <sam> <system> <security>

    1 - Edit user data and passwords
    2 - Syskey status & change
    3 - RecoveryConsole settings
        - - -
    9 - Registry editor, now with full write support!
    q - Quit (you will be asked if there is something to save)


  What to do? [1] -> q

  Hives that have changed:    #  Name    0   - OK

  =========================================================   ¤ Step FOUR: Writing back changes  
=========================================================   About to write file(s) back! Do it? [n] : y

You must answer y, or the changes will not be saved. This is the last chance to change your mind!

  Writing  sam

Only changed files of the registry are actually written back.

If you forgot something, you may run again, else press CTRL-ALT-DEL to reboot.


  ***** EDIT COMPLETE *****

  You can try again if it somehow failed, or you selected wrong   New run? [n] : n  
=========================================================

  * end of scripts.. returning to the shell..   * Press CTRL-ALT-DEL to reboot now (remove floppy first)   * or do whatever you want from the shell..   * However, if you mount something, remember to umount before reboot   * You may also restart the script procedure with 'sh /scripts/main.sh'

  (Please ignore the message about job control, it is not relevant)


  BusyBox v1.1.0-pre1 (2005.12.30-19:45+0000) Built-in shell (ash)   Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

  sh: can't access tty; job control turned off And I got about a gazillion questions on this error message, even if it is mentioned in the FAQ It is from the shell telling it cannot do "job control" which means it cannot handle CTRL-C etc. It HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH YOUR PASSWORD RESET DID NOT WORK! That is caused by a lot of other things.
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers ([How to access computer without password](http://superuser.com/a/999414)). Instead vote to close the question as a duplicate of the one containing the first answer posted.

Comment: A better duplicate by the way is [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/q/72244), you could add your answer there and delete this one and [How to access computer without password](http://superuser.com/a/999414)

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think this user has enough reputation points yet, to do that.

Comment: @paradroid You mean the VTC? If so he can still flag as a duplicate with his rep.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Hmm. Please point out an example for me.

Comment: I think it's too late once you have the rep...