# I changed my Admin account to Standard User (got bad advice). How do I get administrative access back without removing and reinstalling Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

Very recently, I read on this site that one should have at least one Administrator-level account *in addition to* the Administrator account that's hidden by default.  About a year ago, I was reading a lot of articles about security that suggested that one should never use an administrator account for day-to-day operations.  Not having seen the SuperUser advice, and not realizing that I was doing something that was going to mess me up later, I changed my account to a Standard User account, and as a result have lost administrative access to all user accounts.  I did not lose or forget my password (I never had a password on my regular account -- a no-no I suspect).

I have tried using the hidden administrator account to change the account type on my account; this does not work; it defaults back to Standard User.  I have tried creating a new Admin-type account; same result.  I am the only user of this computer, and it is in a home setting. Is there any way to create a non-hidden Administrative privileges account that doesn't entail removing and reinstalling Windows 7 Professional?  This is the OS I'm now using; I have no plans to upgrade to Win 10.

Comment: [Enable the built-in Administrator user](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221).  Instead of a Windows 10 .ISO use a Windows 7 .ISO

Comment: Here's another way as well.... [Another Way](http://superuser.com/questions/1018064/windows-10-administrator-your-account-has-been-disabled-please-see-your-system/1018080#1018080)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)