# Bruteforcing Win 10 Admin

Tags: security

I downloaded Keylemon and set up a facial recognition login screen. Then I changed the password to something long and complicated that I do not remember. Keylemon said that it detected the password had changed and wouldn't let me in without entering it.

Fortunately, I can still get in on another account. Unfortunately, on this account everything except google chrome, notepad, and cmd crashes. It wasn't having this problem on the admin account so I really hope I can get back in.

Is there a way to bruteforce the password with cmd or batch? If so, I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

EDIT: I should also mention that I don't have a disk or USB, and it would take quite a while to get one because I'm 13. I've tried a few ways of password recovery in CMD but none seem to work.

Comment: You should just enable the default built-in Administrator account and change the password of the other Administrator account.  **Any** brute force approaches requires the ability to boot to something other then Windows.

Comment: It won't let me open CMD in administrator without entering the password.

Comment: You'll likely need a either admin access to laptop to have the CMD commands work or else, GET A DISC and do this.... easy as 1-2-3 and fixed!!!   http://superuser.com/questions/1018064/windows-10-administrator-account-has-been-disabled-please-see-your-system-admin/1018080#1018080

Comment: @Victor993 - Opening a command prompt as an Administrator is not one of the steps to enable the built-in Administrator account, I mean it is, but it clearly isn't possible without an Administrator account which you don't have currently.  Check my answer on how to do it properly.

Comment: Up vote on PIMP_JUICE_IT's comment. I have used this solution before on pre-Windows 10 PCs and it is at least worth a shot.