# Unable to log in on Windows 7 Home Basic after creating new user

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, login-screen

I have deleted an user account in my system (HP Pavilion G4) and created a new account, everything was OK.

Next day when I switched on the laptop I saw "Invalid username or password" error in login screen of the system, and account created by me was missing there.

I have also posted the issue on HP Support Forum, you can see [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Unable-to-log-in-on-Windows-7-Home-Basic/m-p/5429662)

Please suggest what should I do.

Thank You

Comment: Ok... You deleted a user account which is not an administrator, I presume. And then you created a new account. Is this new account an administrator? Also, what do you mean by "everything was OK"? Does it mean that on that same day, you logged in and out of that new user account successfully? And on the following day, you cannot log in anymore?

Comment: Yes. the account which I created was Administrator. Everything was ok means I have restarted the system after creating user and I logged in with newly created account successfully. Next day when I switched on the laptop I got the issue.

Comment: [See my post here](http://superuser.com/a/247953/40928), create a new admin account, log into it and use it for several Days logging in and out of new account occasionally (not restart), then delete old user accounts.

Comment: I also have ubuntu OS installed in my PC. I can log in on ubuntu..

Comment: @AshishTiwari Have you tried this solution? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/56864-user-account-password-change-winre.html