# Windows 10 asks for password after profile name change

Tags: windows-10, passwords, windows-registry

I have pretty strange problem. I have been using Windows 10 without any issue for some time and now I went for username change. I went to "netplwiz" and changed my username. I haven't added any password. After that I rebooted my computer and suddenly Windows 10 asks me for password I didn't have.

I have tried to login different ways without any success. After some time of researching the ways to get into my computer I did it via Administrator in Safe Mode. Once I got into Windows 10 I went to User Account Settings. However I can't do anything there (add or delete user accounts). I also can't see any other user accounts except Administrator. I also can't click windows icon on desktop and use search. Only folders can be opened.

At the moment I am making backup of my files just in case I would not be able to recover my system. I was thinking about registry. Maybe it is possible to access user accounts from there? However I don't know how and don't know how to access registry as I am not able to type "regedit" anywhere as search icon is not clickable. 
Is there any way to get everything back working?

Answer (score 0):

The password is probably blank already. Try that first.

Since you can boot into Safe Mode's Administrator account, the next thing to try would be to run `netplwiz` again and undo the change.

You can also change the password or modify the user without `netplwiz`. Open an administrative command prompt and execute the following:

```
net user USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Replace `USERNAME` with the new username, and `PASSWORD` with the password you want to set. (To set a blank password, use `""`.) Once you reboot after doing that, the password you chose there will be the user's password.

If you don't actually have administrative privileges, you'll need to see ["What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?"](https://superuser.com/q/72244/380318)