# Cant find path to registry directory for sam password reset

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-registry, reset

I am trying to reset the password on an old computer (a dell laptop) running windows 7 using an password reset disk

However I cannot find the path to the registry.

Directory `windows/system32/config` is the default and it doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?as i cnt get to it through the administrative account

Comment: Just enable the built-in Administrator account and change the password to the account in question.  Why are you attempting to modify the SAM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score -1):

I have now fixed this, I found a backdoor that allows me access to the command prompt from the login screen so I fixed it from there.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.