# Can I reinstall Windows 7 32-bit Installer in my 64 Bit laptop. Lost it's user account password

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

I forgot my password in my 64-bit laptop and I have a 32-bit installer.
I have not tried it yet because I am not sure, I will run it in BIOS.

Comment: Just download a 64-bit installer much easier the spending time on what might work

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 :**

Firstly, make sure that you have a product key for your current edition. You can usually find it at the back of your laptop as a [COA](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/what-is-the-windows-certificate-of-authenticity) sticker. You can also use 3<sup>rd</sup> party programs like [Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to extract your current product key from the registry if you have reinstalled before.

If you have reinstalled, windows before, then you might have to uninstall your product key before you can use it again. You can find instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759642/reset-windows-activation-remove-license-key) in Stack Overflow.

Secondly, the 32-bit installer of Windows 7 should be the same edition as your current edition or otherwise, your product key will probably not be able to activate it.

You will first have to burn the 32-bit installation on a disc and then you can install it from your bios. You will probably not have any compatibility issues since all 64-bit computers can run 32-bit.

**Option 2 :**

Instead of going in for reinstalling windows, you can [Reset your Windows Password](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password) using a variety of options.

**Option 3 :**

Since all Windows 7 users are eligible for the Windows 10 update, you can first update to Windows 10, backup your data, and then re-install after downloading a Windows 10 iso using their [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10).

If you do this, you will not have any activation problems since Windows 10 will automatically license your installation.