# "User Profile service failed sign-in" - microsoft proposed solutions not working

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

My friend has this problem with this admin account on his Windows 7.

His guest account works.

I found a microsoft help page and tried two of the solutions so far - both failed.

1)
If i am logged in as admin "safe-mode" or guest "normal-mode" I can not create a new user account through "control panel - user accounts" - the functionality simply does not open/work when I click it (this was my initial idea - to create a new admin account and move data over to that)

2)
If I run microsoft "fix-it" for he issue on the guest account - it runs, but nothing is changed. I can not successfully run in on the admin account in safe mode.

Right now, I am a litle at a loss. I had this problem myself once, but I had a backup admin account that worked which I used to fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: If you are able to login to the user account in Safe Mode, its all about removing a registry entry. Are you sure you have tried [this solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/947215)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have tried restarting in safe mode?

I have had this issue before also and can't quite remember what weird solution I used.

Try using safe mode, logging in and renaming the admin account's user folder in C:\windows\users to a .bak so that Windows has to recreate it maybe?