# Reset password of Administrator Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, administrator, password-recovery

How to reset password of Contoso/Administrator with Windows Server 2012? I'll login with that user but I'm forgotten the password. How could I reset that password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search on google, you can find plenty of urls. Anyways, I have found the solution. Give a try and let us know:

To reset the password on your Windows 2012 server, simply complete the following steps:

- Boot from the Micrsoft Windows Server 2012 DVD
- From the Windows Setup menu, click **“Next”**.
- Select **“Repair your computer”**
- Under Choose and option, click on **“Troubleshoot”**.
- Under Advanced options, click **“Command Prompt”**.
- At the command prompt, run the following commands:
  **d:

  cd windows\system32

  ren Utilman.exe Utilman.exe.old

  copy cmd.exe Utilman.exe**
- Close the command prompt and then click **“Continue”**.
- The server should now boot and present the logon screen. Here click **Windows Key + U**.
- At the prompt you can now change the password, by typing the following command:
  **net user administrator Password123**

  *This will set the password for the Administrator user to be Password123 (case sensitive).*

  Closing the command prompt, you should now be able to log back onto the server using the password you have provided in the last step.

***Source:*** http://www.kieranlane.com/2013/09/18/resetting-administrator-password-windows-2012/