# Reinstall windows on admin computer

Tags: laptop, installation, passwords, operating-systems, protected

I have a good laptop that my work gave me 3 -years ago. I'll be leaving them soon and I can keep the computer (they don't want it back). There is windows 7 on it and its admin password protected. 
They can't give me the password to unlock it, basically is take it as is or leave it. 
I was wondering if by replacing the HD with a fresh one, would I be able to install a new copy of windows? I believe the bios is  protected as well so I can't chose log in sequence.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: You should research how to reset the BIOS password on the device.  If you can't reset that, it means, you won't be able to change the boot order.  Which means you can't install an OS on the existing HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unplug the battery which powers the Bios. leave it unplugged for 15 minutes and then format the HD with G Parted and then do a fresh install of your OS.