# Lost Administrator Password of a HP Pro X2 612 G1 with 64-bit Windows 8.1 installed

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, administrator, password-recovery, reset

I've just bought a HP Pro x2 G1 and only have the user name and password.

I am trying to update and download new drivers but can't because it keeps asking for the admin name and password. The user name seems correct but the password is not.

Is there a way to reset or retrieve this password?

Comment: Do you have an `Microsoft Account` ? That will help if you have. Inform me and I will suggest an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](http://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score 0):

there are several way to retrieve - or reset - a password for a local Windows account. I personally always use https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ when i need to do that. It can create a bootable usb stick which does exactly what it says on the tin.