# Switching back to Microsoft account to login to Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10

I turned on a laptop that's been dormant for a couple years, logged in.  Once it had internet access, it complained that I needed to login again with my Microsoft account, as my Microsoft account password had changed since it was last online.  I didn't have my account info handy, so I followed the prompts to create a local account instead.  (That's fine... I didn't want that Microsoft account anyway.)

Upon clicking log out to sign in again, I can't sign in again.  I just created the account, and am totally sure of the password I typed in (though I suppose it's possible a keyboard key was acting up or something... I did enter it and confirm it and this worked).  When I try to sign-in now, it tells me the password is wrong.

I know how have access to my Microsoft account password.  Is there any way to switch back to the regular Microsoft account login instead of the local account?

Comment: Realistically, you would need to [reset your password on the local account](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password) and then [convert it to a Microsoft account](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5375-microsoft-account-switch-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @Run5k Ok, thank you.  Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it as the solution?

Comment: Well, I could easily author an answer for how to convert the local account to a Microsoft account, but I think that the crucial step is to reset the local account password and I can't take credit for that.  I would simply "up-vote" the proposed password reset answer that worked for you.  Thanks for the consideration, though!

Comment: @Brad - There is also a duplicate on how to link your account to a MS Account (and how to unlink your account by the way).  So submitting yet another answer on how to reset your local account's password wouldn't really be helpful.  *I have an answer how to do in my answer list.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no way to sign in with a previously-used Microsoft account, once it has been "converted" to a local account.

The solution in my case was to unlock the Administrator account with chntpw on a Ubuntu Live USB drive.