# How to access the SAM file in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, password-recovery

In the past I have cracked Windows passwords with a Live Linux disk and navigating to the SAM file. In windows 10 it seems this information is stored on the cloud. Is there a way to find this locally on the machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SAM hive still exists in Windows 10, and it's in the same place. For local non-Microsoft accounts, the format does not appear to have changed; the NTLM hash is still the 16 bytes before the last 8 bytes of the `V` value.

For accounts that sign in with a Microsoft account password, the `CachedLogonInfo` value contains the cached password ([source](http://www.top-password.com/blog/the-secrets-of-windows-8-microsoft-account/)). Unfortunately, it's not just an NTLM hash, so normal Windows hash cracking tools won't work on it. If that page is correct and the algorithm is indeed much stronger - which would make sense, since it would be very bad if an MS account password could be retrieved from a workstation - then cracking it would take an extremely long time considering the complexity requirements Microsoft puts in place.

Comment: Thanks for the source it was great and mostly what I was looking for. I possibly should have rephrased my question. Instead of cracking if I were to just delete the cached credentials would it unlock the system?

Comment: @Joe I suspect that there's some other bookkeeping that identifies it as a Microsoft account. If you just need to get into the machine, you might use something like [this approach](http://superuser.com/a/247953/380318) to create a new administrative user.

Comment: Thanks again. I have seen that method before definitely a neat trick.