# (Windows 10) offline nt password registry editor fails

Tags: windows-10, passwords, reset

I forgot my password on a Windows 10 machine. So I tried the offline nt password registry editor to clear it. But whenever I start the cd, it cannot find the partion:

[image: PICTURE]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: What format is the disk?  What format is the partition?  Is the file system encrypted?  Is the drive encrypted?  To avoid these types of troubles, why not just use [one of the alternate methods of resetting your Windows password](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)?

Comment: What do you mean by encrypted? And I only have a 700 mb disk so I cant install Ubuntu...

Comment: Re: Encryption -- Is the drive and/or file system encrypted? Bitlocker? TrueCrypt? BIOS-level hardware passwords, etc?  Re: Ubuntu -- There's several methods on the question I linked to.  My go-to is the sethc.exe hack (search those answers for info on that).  I requested the additional information because as-is there's not enough information in your question for us to give you an answer.

Comment: The sethc.exe  doesnt work. When I try to use it, I have to use a password.

Comment: And I also dont have a install disk for windows.

Comment: @KevinMeyer So download one.  You not having an Windows 10 installation disk isn't a reason not to use it, to solve your problem, and enable the built-in Administration account to chnage the password on your existing account.  So I suggest you do that, check my answer, on how to do exactly that

Comment: Using the correct solution to your problem is important.  The tool you attempted to use, is NOT, the correct solution