# Windows 10 reset password on CMD is not working

Tags: windows, command-line, usb, passwords

I have tried resetting my password of the local account with admin permissions. (not domain account)

Since I cannot access the CMD option in the  page (I have to enter the password to access CMD), I made a Windows bootable USB drive and booted from the USB.

I then pressed Shift + F10 to open the CMD window in administrator, and entered:

```
net user username /passwordreq:no
net user username new_password
```

Both commands say **"The operation completed successfully."**, and I thought all the job was completed.

**However, when I booted into Windows after finishing the commands and removing the USB (to the login page) and entered the new password, it still says "Wrong Password".. even I have changed to another password.**

I was using Windows 10 RS3. Is Windows 10 different from other operating systems when using the `net` command in CMD?

What should I do? Help!

Comment: “Is Windows 10 different from other operating systems when using the net command in CMD?” - No, it is not different.

Comment: Then, why the new password changed by CMD is not working in the login page? Even the command that enables admin account doesn't work in the login page when I launched the commands in CMD booted by the USB. I changed the drive to C: drive.

Comment: Unclear based on the information you provided.  You asked a “Yes or No” question, unclear the reason you cannot reset the password, from within Windows.

Comment: I cannot log in to the Windows account in the login page. So I made a bootable USB drive with Windows ISO and entered some commands in CMD booted by the USB. However, since the login page after the commands says the changed password is wrong, I think the operations didn't work actually.

Comment: If you need to enable the built-in Administrator account then see my answer on the subject.  “Entered some commands” doesn’t tell me anything

Comment: I'm wondering why the commands are not applied. The password should be changed if I enter those commands, but it didn't.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator, log into it, and create the user with it.  Starting to get the idea your not even authorized to do whatever your trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score 1):

Those commands were run from the bootable Windows drive (WinPE?), so they applied to that instance of Windows, not your main system.

If you need more information on how to reset a forgotten password, please refer to [the answers to this Superuser question.](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: Then, according to the answer in the following thread, do I have to boot with my Windows 10 installation USB and enter those commands in CMD? I can not access CMD in <Advanced options> since it is also locked by the same account password.

Comment: @FelixLee So enable the built-in Administrator account.

Comment: I tried entering the command to enable admin account in the CMD in Windows USB drive, but it doesn't work and I can not see the account in the login page.

Comment: I think there is some confusion on how the net commands work. They are only aware of the version of windows they are run from. It doesn't matter if it is a bootable USB or the install disk. The tools mentioned in the linked post work because they look for your install of windows and are designed to work with it.

Comment: If you were referring to other commands like replacing sethc with cmd, then they can be run from the bootable USB or install disk. The drive letters mentioned may be different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an elevated command prompt inside the Windows environment that you are trying to change the password. If you can’t log in to any admin account on the computer, theres a workaround it. Boot from USB, holding shift+F10, then run these commands

```
Cd c:/Windows/system32
Ren utilman.exe utilman.exe.bak
Copy cmd.exe utilman.bak
```

Restart like normal, and at the bottom right corner, click the ease of access icon. Boom command prompt with admin rights.