# Windows 10 OS Disk write protection

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, write-protect

Here is my problem.

I have lost my *Win10* password and in search of solutions plugged in the hard drive with the *Windows10* into another machine with another OS. 
However, I discovered that I am unable to change system files, even as an administrator or root. There are writable files on the disk, so I think it is some feature of NTFS file system. Also, unwritable files are readable, so they aren't encrypted. But shouldn't another OS have the whole disk writable? How is this possible and how to remove the write protection? I have tried editing files in Windows\System32\ on *WinXP*, *Win7* and *Linux*. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  If you don't mind me asking, *why* are you trying to edit files in the `Windows\System32` folder?

Comment: See my answer here...https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928

Comment: I am trying to edit security files and .exe files. Trying to figure out how things work.

Comment: Thanks, Moab, but my primary goal is understanding the problem. That OS holds no valueble files, so hard-resetting it will also do for me.

Comment: The reason you can't access the disc is probably that the OS is hibernated, which is the default for Shut Down. If you start up, then _Restart_ from the log-on screen, you can stop it when the UEFI/BIOS appears: then the system will be fully shut down and you should be able access it from another OS.

Comment: The dupe does provide not an answer (as it currently stands), it covers up to Win8 but not Win10, at least none of the answers address it.