# I have lost my admin rights and locked up the admin account and signed in as a local account

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have lost my admin rights and locked up my admin account.
I am signed in with a local account without admin rights.
I am unable to run any program with admin access and using "run as administrator".
What should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SuperUser!

When you are fully locked out of a Server 2008 system the recovery is going to be similar to that of a Windows 7 system.

You have two main options:

1. Break in:

[What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

2. Reinstall