# Windows System Repair Toolkits

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, system-repair-disc

I'm updating my current roster of go-to utilities for my CD/USB toolkit for service calls.

Right now I carry the basics - installers for TeamViewer, a few Piriform programs (Ccleaner, Recuva, etc), and a few malwarebytes programs.

A few automated/compiled toolkits I've considered are InstantHousecall, Ultra Virus Killer ( UVK), and IOBit.

I could continue using my individual tools but having a suite seems more convenient.

Has anyone used any of these suites?

What would be the advantages of keeping the current individual programs as opposed to using an all in one suite and vice versa?

Comment: What I have done personally is I have an FTP site and then a program that basically grabs installers in a list from that FTP site to which I can always grow. Perhaps something along those lines would work for you? You could use a hosting site or even google drive. As far as installing them in a suite you can make custom scripts that go down the list to install one after another

Comment: I always have the windows erd boot disks in my tool kit....https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928

Comment: I fear the close votes on this, but before any of that happens, I'd drop CCleaner & IObit entirely & look at [Windows Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) [used to be called 'all in one'.]

Comment: @Tetsujin This article and reading reviews on the alternative-to site is how I arrived at some of the options listed above.  https://www.technibble.com/what-are-the-best-automated-windows-repair-tools/ What's your argument for dropping CCleaner or IObit?

Comment: I don't like tools that will indiscriminately delete things; they sometimes get it wrong or the user presses the wrong button. The reason I recommend WIndows all in one [mentioned in your link so they like it too] is it's really hard to make it break something, even for a total novice, & the freeware version is enough for most people.