# How to obtain admin password hashes through guest (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, security, passwords, user-accounts

Recently i changed my admin password and forgot exactly what i changed it to. This means i can only use my computer via my user account, so things like installing new software is now impossible.

Is there a way i can obtain the password hash for my admin account using only my user account? I already have password crackers(hash suite and ophcracker iirc) on the computer, so the hash is all i need.

I cant install new software without an admin password so i can only use portables(rufusp seems to be an exception oddly enough, ). This also means i cant burn software to my usb i can use to crack my computer, but I’ve heard rightclicking the iso and selecting mount before copying the files to the usb would work. I haven’t tried it out though, so I cant say anything about that yet.

Additionally, stuff like pwdump and fgdump are being blocked by norton firewall, which i (again) cant change without admin rights. This means i cant directly dump the SAM or SYSTEM files the hashes are supposed to be in to a .txt unless there’s a way to bypass that as well.

Is there any other way i can get to admin hashes from my user account?
(While resetting the password is a valid option, I’d prefer getting the original password if only for the catharsis of figuring out just what the hell i set it to if it wasnt the one i remember it was)

To reiterate; I HAVE *NO* ADMIN ACCESS WHATSOEVER.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "Is there a way I can obtain the password hash for my admin account using only my user account?" - No;  There is third-party software that will reset you the password for you.

Comment: @ Anaksunaman I actually did just download it, can it make a completely new user with admin rights on my computer?

Comment: See this....https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928