# Can't boot to BIOS and I don't have the Windows 10 user password. What can I do?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, user-accounts, password-recovery

I tried searching for this question but I can't find a solution to this. I was given a laptop to reformat and do a fresh Windows 10 install but the laptop won't boot to BIOS (or UEFI). I tried every possible key (F2,F10,Del,Esc,etc). It always boot directly to Windows 10. I think the bios is someway locked.

When I search information about booting to BIOS on this particular laptop (BGH E920TV) the recommendation is to boot to UEFI from the Windows special restart options. But I can't do that, because I can't log into windows (I don't have the user password).

It becomes clear that I have to remove the drive from the laptop and get the password somehow. I first thought about using the "utilman.exe" trick, but this trick is patched now. It no longer works on latest Windows 10.

So I'm kind of lost here. I could extract the disk and reformat it. But I don't know what will happen with the laptop if I put an empty disk. I'm afraid I could make it unusable (because it boots only to this windows 10 installation and there are not other booting options...).

Can you recommend me what to do? I can connect the drive to other laptop (using a SATA to USB cable). Then I will have full access to the drive (I don't think it's encrypted). From that point, how can I reset a user password? Or enable a new administrator password?

Thanks

Comment: Get the Windows Recovery USB from the manufacturer's Support Site and boot with that. The Recovery USB will work. Also try a bootable Windows 10 USB Key made from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. That should also work. Delete all partitions and let the installer build Windows.

Comment: Bios is not blocked, it is resuming from hybrid sleep, if you can boot from a disk and delete the hiberfil.sys file on the root of the drive, then F key should allow you to enter the bios now, see this to reset your user password>>>https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. At the end I took apart the laptop and connected the HDD to another PC. From that PC I changed the user password using this free tool: http://www.cdslow.org.ru/en/ntpwedit/

From that point I was able to boot to windows again. And then I was able to boot to UEFI from Windows 10 troubleshooting options. Finally I reinstalled a fresh copy of Windows.

I've never discovered how to call the BIOS setup while booting. The only way to access it was from the Windows 10 troubleshooting options (https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10).

Anyway, the problem is solved now. Thanks!