# Accessing locked, encrypted Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, password-recovery

I've set a (short and simple) password on a Windows 10 user account. Immediately after setting it, I wanted to test it and logged out of the user account. The computer then didn't let me in anymore, even though I am 100% sure the password is exactly as I had set it just 20 seconds ago. Variations of the password also don't work (caps/num lock, other keyboards, etc).

After trying to remove the password via the registry from a bootable Windows USB stick, I noticed that the hard disk is encrypted with BitLocker (which I haven't set up though before). Inspecting the protectors `manage-bde -protectors c: -get` only returns the status "unknown", but the main drive (with the relevant registry) is not accessible anyway. There are no other user accounts on the machine.

**What other options are there for restoring access to the computer?** All options in the (blue) recovery menu (restore, etc) require a password as well. Ideally I'd like to keep the data of course.

Comment: Are you sure BitLocker protection is actually enabled instead of Device Encryption.  Unless you have EFS setup you can safely reset the password to the account using the built-in Administrator account.  The BitLocker protector should typically be either a TPM or a Password. A protector not being assigned is a sign that BitLocker is improperly configured.  BitLocker is NEVER configured without user interaction.  Device Encryption depending on the type of device might be enabled by default but the key is automatically backed up to your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: Do you have multiple keyboard layouts? That issue can happen if the password is created in one layout and the login dialog initializes with a different one. Try using the onscreen keyboard, https://www.alphr.com/windows-log-in-without-keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the password or the BitLocker recovery key, then there is nothing you can do to access or recover the data on the drive.

If you could bypass the encryption, it wouldnt be a very useful encryption tool.