# Windows 10 administrator password recovery

Tags: windows, windows-10, password-recovery

I would like to recover a Windows 10 administrator password. I've tried some "password recovery" software, and all the options I've looked at remove your old password and let you reset it, is there a way to recover the password instead?

Comment: Short answer: No. Password encryption is one way for security reasons.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928

Comment: It really seems like there's no way. I'll try cracking and see what happens. And thanks for answering!